# How do I get wireless working on an ASUS Notebook U56E?

Tags: wireless, intel-wireless

On version 11.04 Ubuntu I have access to my Wifi, but after I upgrade to 11.10, I can never get wifi at all. If I'm wired then it works, but if I'm not then it doesnt work.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This is a known bug, please see:https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/907657. There is a solution listed there.

Answer (score 3):

#### For 12.04 and 11.10

I had the same problem with the same computer enter these commands and it will be solved.

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlagn
sudo modprobe iwlagn bt_coex_active=0
```

If it worked you need to make it permanent.

To make the change permanent:

```
gksu gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwl.conf
```

Copy/paste this line into the new file:

```
options iwlagn bt_coex_active=0
```

Save and quit.

After you do this you will experience very slow internet connection but it can be solved by making iwlag not use n and it can be done with these commands.

```
sudo rmmod -f iwlagn
sudo modprobe iwlagn 11n_disable=1
```

if you see it made a difference once again you must make it perminent..

```
gksu gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwlagn-disable11n.conf
options iwlagn 11n_disable=1
```

Save and quit.
And thats all

Thank you WBMachinery for this.

Bug report:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/876147

Answer (score 2):

I arrived here trying to find out why the broadcom wireless in my acer aspire laptop was performing slowly. The originally proposed fix on the fedora bug worked for me:

> Please create a file called /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf with a single line like this:
>
> options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
>
> Then reboot (or "modprobe -r iwlwifi ; modprobe iwlwifi" as root).

I also had to rmmod brcmsmac, which is the broadcom specific bit, so pay attention to your module dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

found this buried deep in bug report:

create /etc/modprobe.d/iwl.conf with the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0
```

or

```
#!/bin/sh
options iwlagn bt_coex_active=0
```

the second one worked for me