# Broadcom BCM4313 wireless too slow

Tags: 11.10, wireless, broadcom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't get into Wifi on my ASUS Notebook U56E?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104651/cant-get-into-wifi-on-my-asus-notebook-u56e)

Hi I have an HP pavilion g6 series with a slow Internet connection I tried WiFi and LAN but always the same problem my broadcom is a corporation BCM4313.

I also tried Fedora the last Version but couldn't get any connection, but on Windows 7 all worked just fine.

Comment: Are other machines slow too, or is it just yours?  You might want to make sure it is an issue with your specific machine / OS, and not your router, modem, ISP, etc...

Comment: Check out my answer at http://askubuntu.com/questions/104651/cant-get-into-wifi-on-my-asus-notebook-u56e/114585#114585

Good luck.

Comment: thanks Dave it's solved now thanks everyone for the help

Comment: @Dave Could you repost your solution here. And belhauss, could you then mark it as your Accepted Answer? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The question asker solved this issue by following the steps in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104651/cant-get-into-wifi-on-my-asus-notebook-u56e/114585#114585) to the question [*Can't get into Wifi on my ASUS Notebook U56E?*](https://askubuntu.com/q/104651/24694)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running the right firmware and that the right module is being loaded.. you can use dmesg|grep firmware to see if there are any kernal based firmware error messages. look up the firmware and drivers needed for your device and make sure that they are both correct. most broadcom chips require additonal firmware that cannot be installed by default out of legality