# Unable to connect to wireless internet on an Acer Iconia W500 with an Atheros AR9285

Tags: wireless, 12.04, acer, atheros

I'm using an Acer Iconia W500, and immediately after upgrading from 11.10 to 12.04, it is unable to access the internet. It was able to access the internet just fine before the upgrade. It seems to be connecting to the wi-fi network, but I've tried several different websites on several different browsers and none of them can display any pages. I am able to access the internet just fine through the exact same wi-fi connection on my Toshiba Satellite running Linux Mint.

Here are the results from `sudo lspci -v`:

```
01:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01) 
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device e031
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17 
    Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K] 
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [60] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 00-15-17-ff-ff-24-14-12
    Capabilities: [170] Power Budgeting <?>
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k 
    Kernel modules: ath9k
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information?

Comment: @Jorge Castro
Please let me know which relevant commands to run, and I'll run them and post the results. My ability to copy and paste is limited, since I'm using a different computer to access the internet.

Comment: `lspci -v` should be enough, look for something about the wireless card, either Broadcom, Intel, Ralink, or maybe Atheros. We only need the model # of the wireless card

Comment: I was able to copy and paste using LibreOffice and a USB flash drive. The complete results are up there now.

Comment: Same card, same issue, different computer. I'm connected to a wireless network but I'm unable to ping anything but myself.

Comment: Impossible to know this now, but this could be a dupe of my own question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/165326/ar9285-wireless-yet-another-on-acer-aspire-one-532h-2676

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem.  This is to help with the Ask Ubuntu Clean Up. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try my answer and see if it works.  Just enter the first two lines of code and test wifi.

[How do I get wireless working on an ASUS Notebook U56E?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104651/cant-get-into-wifi-on-my-asus-notebook-u56e/114585#114585)

Comment: Both of those commands gave me the following:
`WARNING: All config files need .conf: /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist, it will be ignored in a future release.
WARNING: All config files need .conf: /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.save, it will be ignored in a future release.`

The second command said the same thing but also had `FATAL: Module iwlgn not found.` at the end.

Comment: This won't work, totally different wireless card.

Answer (score 0):

you could try a newer mainline kernel if it's a driver problem, but you should be careful if you use a proprietary graphics-driver.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/