# AR9285 Wireless (Yet another) on Acer Aspire One 532h-2676

Tags: 12.04, wireless, atheros

There are literally hundreds of questions with people asking about this wireless device  on askubuntu.org. I've spent about 12 hours trying to get it working, to no avail. It's time to solicit some expert help.

**Information:**

- Acer Aspire One 532h-2676
- AR9285 Wireless
- Ubuntu 12.04 / Updated via ethernet connection (Ditched
  Windows - so this needs to work!)

**Problem:**

The wireless device connects to the router and receives an internal IP, however, no amount of finagling seems to be able to provide me with anything save momentary internet access. I can `ping -c 10 192.168.0.XX` my address, but I can't ping the router (192.168.0.1) or the internet (google.ca/com).

**What I've tried and read elsewhere on askubuntu/linuxforums/ubuntuforums**

- Installed `sudo apt-get install linux-backports-net-${uname -r)` (Expected compatibility drivers)
- Edited `../ath9k.conf` with `options ath9k nohcrypt=1` (Read post about hardware encryption problem)
- Tried using `wicd` instead (Read post that this worked for some pre 12.04)
- Fully removed and reinstalled NM `sudo apt-get purge network-manager*` ... `sudo apt-get install network-manager*`(Read post that this worked for some)

**Details People Usually Ask for on Other Questions**

```
$ sudo lshw -C network

  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: AR8132 Fast Ethernet
       vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eth1
       version: c0
       serial: 70:5a:b6:d8:99:53
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl1c driverversion=1.0.1.0-NAPI firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:45 memory:57000000-5703ffff ioport:5000(size=128)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
       vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 78:e4:00:24:a0:19
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.2.0-26-generic-pae firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.19 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:17 memory:56000000-5600ffff
```

---

```
$ rfkill list all

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

---

```
$ lspci

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation N10 Family DMI Bridge
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation N10 Family Integrated Graphics Controller
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation N10 Family Integrated Graphics Controller
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 02)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 02)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 2 (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev e2)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation NM10 Family LPC Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH7 Family SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 02)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8132 Fast Ethernet (rev c0)
02:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
```

---

dmesg at startup

http://pastebin.com/GKRMmc93

(It's set to be removed in a month, if you see something in there that identifies the problem please denote it and I'll update the question with the line(s) in question so some other unlucky person can `dmesg | grep ...` for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same problem here and traced it to a conflict in two hardware `rfkill` switches.

In `syslog` I noted the following details:

```
NetworkManager[668]: <info> found WiFi radio killswitch rfkill0 (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:02:00.0/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill0) (driver (unknown))
NetworkManager[668]: <info> found WiFi radio killswitch rfkill1 (at /sys/devices/platform/acer-wmi/rfkill/rfkill1) (driver acer-wmi)
```

I seem to have solved it by blacklisting `acer-wmi` in this manner:

```
echo blacklist acer-wmi | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-acer-wmi
```

You can then reboot or enter `sudo rmmod acer-wmi`.

Comment: This worked for me.  I recently installed ubuntu 12.04 on my Aspire One, and out of the box, the wifi worked fine, but after a particular update, everything went to crap.  Constant reconnects every few seconds. This solution worked for me on my Aspire One 532h-2588, though I'd imagine it'd work for anyone with the same series of network with the same wirelesss card.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jeroen, I'm going to try it out. I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: Workeked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Did not realize, there is another thread.

I am pasting my answer from the other thread. Does askubuntu provide a way to consolidate threads?

Here is what helped me. It is not perfect, but works.

Follow the instructions in this threat http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1286503&page=5

When you reboot, the wifi does not work. Now, what you do is suspend the laptop and resume. Surprisingly, the network is on when it resumes. I have been using this, and for now I can get by, as a suspend-resume cycle only takes about a minute.

My setup is an asus u32u with AR9285 and the problem started as soon as I upgraded to 13.04