# AR9285 Wireless network problem Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: wireless, 13.04, atheros

I just installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my new Lenovo Ideapad using the live USB. My problem is that I cannot connect to my wireless network. My wireless adapter is recognized as Atheros Communications Inc AR9285 Wireless network adapter.

Comment: There are about 100 posts on this particular wireless device on here. This post (my own) shows you the type of information needed to diagnose wireless problems. Try duplicating the output that I've provided http://askubuntu.com/questions/165326/ar9285-wireless-yet-another-on-acer-aspire-one-532h-2676 I personally haven't had much luck with this (ie, none of the fixes have provided a persistent solution).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what helped me.  It is not perfect, but works.

Follow the instructions in this threat http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1286503&page=5

When you reboot, the wifi does not work.  Now, what you do is suspend the laptop and resume.  Surprisingly, the network is on when it resumes.  I have been using this, and for now I can get by, as a suspend-resume cycle only takes about a minute.