# Wired connection does not work after fixing wireless problem for ASUS U56E and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, asus

After fixing what appears to be a universal bug concerning wireless on an ASUS U56E notebook running Ubuntu 12.04, my wired connection has stopped working.  The fix I found was:

[How do I get Wireless working on an Asus notebook U56E](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104651/how-do-i-get-wireless-working-on-an-asus-notebook-u56e)

When the wireless works, the wired does not. When I remove the command from the file that makes the fix permanent and restart, the wireless no longer works and the wired works again.

Still new to Linux, so I may be overlooking something, but does anyone have any thoughts on this problem?

Wireless and wired hardware info:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N + WiMAX 6150 [8086:0885] (rev 67)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:1083] (rev c0)
```

The conf file is named: `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlagn.conf` and the content is

```
options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add details about your wireless and wired cards from this terminal command: lspci -nn | grep -e 0200 -e 0280. The pipe symbol is on the right side of my US keyboard on the same key with \.

Comment: Which sequence do you have in the conf file? bt_coex_active or 11n_disable or both? Have you tried first one and then the other and then both? Is or are the parameters in iwlwifi.conf?

Comment: The conf file is named: [gksu gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwlagn.conf] and the content is [options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0]. Does this answer your question? There is only this one command in the sequence.

Comment: Please delete the file: sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/iwlagn.conf and write a new one: gksu gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf. Add a single line: options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1  Reboot and let us have your report.

Comment: Both wireless and wired function normally after reboot. Thank you chili555!

Comment: So I can get a few reputation points, I am going to convert my comments to an answer I hope you'll accept. Glad it's working.

Comment: Interesting, after one reboot both wireless and wired were working. Now, after another reboot, only wireless is working.

Comment: Your ethernet uses the driver atl1c. Does it run if you simply load the driver? sudo modprobe atl1c If so, add it to /etc/modules.

Comment: @chili555 Still does not work if I load driver.

Comment: Please load the driver: sudo modprobe atl1c. Now look for error or warning messages here: dmesg | grep atl1

Comment: No error or warning messages.

Comment: Are there any interesting clues in the message logs? sudo modprobe atl1c && dmesg | grep -e atl1c -e eth0

Comment: This comes up once-- [atl1c 0000:04:00.0: atl1c: eth0 NIC Link is Down],and this a dozen times or so -- [ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready]

Comment: Are there any listings here for eth0? If you are using Network Manager, there should be none: cat /etc/network/interfaces

Comment: No listings for eth0. Just: auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

Comment: Please reboot so we have a clean slate. Turn the wireless switch to OFF. Be sure a known good ethernet cable is attached. Then run this in a terminal: dmesg > peter.txt. Find the text file peter.txt in your user directory and paste it here and give us the link. http://paste.ubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

Please delete the file:

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/iwlagn.conf
```

and write a new one:

```
gksu gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

Add a single line:

```
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

Reboot and let us have your report.